# WMI Get All Monitors Not Returning All Monitors

Tags: c#, wmi, monitor

I am using WMI `Win32_MonitorDesktop` to get all the monitors information on the system.

However it only returns one. I have tried it on several computers, and they definitely have multiple monitors on them, connected and working.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher monitorObjectSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");

foreach (ManagementObject monitor in monitorObjectSearch.Get())
{
      Debug.WriteLine(monitor["Description"]);
}
```

Does anyone know why i'm only getting 1 monitor returned?

Also if I assign the return value of monitorObjectSearch.Get() to a variable, I am unable to evaluate the Count property in the immediate window as the function always times out.

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista, hardware that is not compatible with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) returns inaccurate property values for instances of this class. (From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: That says it will return inaccurate property values, the values I get for the single monitor are correct.

I'm only getting 1 monitor.

Comment: When using Screen.AllScreens I have 2 in the array, however I can't get the "nice" name of the monitor from here.

Comment: At home now. I can confirm this error. When checking for CIM_LogicalDevice, I do see two monitors as Win32_PnPEntity but only one of them is of type Win32_DesktopMonitor. (Vista, 64-bits.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/workaround?
I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue still, running Windows 7 64bit, any solutions? I am running from a service and in debug Screen.AllScreens gets 2, but in release it gets 1. (WMI has the same problem for me)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the monitors are set up in a horizontal span mode (NV and ATI cards) which effectively make multiple monitor setups into one *big* monitor? Otherwise, I'll continue to have a think..

Also the [MSDN quite specifically states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122%28VS.85%29.aspx) that if this WMI call is used with anything pre-vista it will yield inaccurate results!?

Comment: The setup is two different desktops not as one big monitor. I'm on vista, both 64 and 32.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to resolve this problem using WMI on many systems (from WinXP-SP3 up to Win10), and I got different results on different machines. 
There are two tables, where current monitor setting can be stored. First is *Win32_DesktopMonitor* in *cimv2* namespace, second is *WMIMonitorID* in *wmi* namespace.
If one of them has only one record (in multi display setting), then second will have all of entries.

Then to get driver name of monitor, one should find devices with PnPDeviceID found in records from those tables in *Win32_PnPEntity* table, in *cimv2* namespace. You can check sample solution [here](http://japrogbits.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-wmi-to-query-monitor-information.html).

Answer (score 1):

This certainly does not answer your actual question but most reliable way of figuring out monitor information is to read following registry:

```
"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\"
```

under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code from wmi (win32_Desktopmonitor) on a windows 7 machine. It doen't work there as well, in the sense that only 1 monitor is returned, where there are really two.

Also Screen.Allscreens.Length, only returns 1 monitor. The only way to get the system to return 2 monitors, is to extend the desktop to the two monitors, but that's not what most people do.