# How to get the number of monitors connected to the PC in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen

I need to detect the number of monitors that are physically connected to the computer (to decide if the screen configuration is in single, extended, or duplicate mode).

Both
`System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length` and `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MonitorCount` return the number of virtual screens (desktops).

I need that if there are 2+ monitors connected to the PC, I can decide between duplicate/extended mode using this value, but I can't decide if there is only one physical monitor connected to the PC, and therefore the screen configuration is in single screen mode.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher monitorObjectSearch = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
    int Counter = monitorObjectSearch.Get().Count;
```

Answer found on the following question:

[WMI Get All Monitors Not Returning All Monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422065/wmi-get-all-monitors-not-returning-all-monitors)

**Update**

Try the following function it detects unplugging the monitor:

```
    private int GetActiveMonitors()
    {
        int Counter = 0;
        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher monitorObjectSearch = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
        foreach (ManagementObject Monitor in monitorObjectSearch.Get())
        {
            UInt16 Status = 0;
            try
            {
                Status = (UInt16)Monitor["Availability"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error handling if you want to
                continue;
            }
            if (Status == 3)
                Counter++;

        }
        return Counter;
    }
```

Here are a list for the status: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Maybe you need to increase the counter on a other statuscode as well. Check the link for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but if I have 2 monitors connected to the computer and then I disconnect one, counter still returns incorrect (old) count -> 2 (until next start of Windows)...

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work - now it detects only one physical monitor if I have screen configuration set to "Duplicate" (in duplicate mode, second monitor has status 8 - Off Line, the same status as if monitor is disconnected)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Xanatos answer, I created simple helper class to detect the screens configuration:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ScreensConfigurationDetector
{
    public static ScreensConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        int physicalMonitors = GetActiveMonitors();
        int virtualMonitors = Screen.AllScreens.Length;

        if (physicalMonitors == 1)
        {
            return ScreensConfiguration.Single;
        }

        return physicalMonitors == virtualMonitors 
            ? ScreensConfiguration.Extended 
            : ScreensConfiguration.DuplicateOrShowOnlyOne;
    }

    private static int GetActiveMonitors()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        ManagementObjectSearcher monitorObjectSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");
        foreach (ManagementObject Monitor in monitorObjectSearch.Get())
        {
            try
            {
                if ((UInt16)Monitor["Availability"] == 3)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                continue;
            }

        }
        return counter;
    }
}

public enum ScreensConfiguration
{
    Single,
    Extended,
    DuplicateOrShowOnlyOne
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor" query might not work properly after Vista. I spent hours looking for a solution but none of them managed to handle this properly for Windows 7 and newer. Based on [Dominik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044469/11992866);

```cs
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where service=\"monitor\"");
int numberOfMonitors = searcher.Get().Count;
```

will return the count of physical monitors. With this change, his helper class also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way I found to get a monitor count in WPF was to listen for WM_DISPLAYCHANGE to know when mionitors are connected and disconnected and then use EnumDisplayMonitors to get the monitor count.  Here's the code.

**Hook into WndProc for the WM_DISPLAYCHANGE message.**

```
public partial class MainWindow : IDisposable
{
...
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            if (msg == WM_DISPLAYCHANGE)
            {
                int lparamInt = lParam.ToInt32();

                uint width = (uint)(lparamInt & 0xffff);
                uint height = (uint)(lparamInt >> 16);

                int monCount = ScreenInformation.GetMonitorCount();
                int winFormsMonCount = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Length;

                _viewModel.MonitorCountChanged(monCount);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

**Get the display count**

```
public class ScreenInformation
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct ScreenRect
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lpRect, MonitorEnumProc callback, int dwData);

    private delegate bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref ScreenRect pRect, int dwData);

    public static int GetMonitorCount()
    {
        int monCount = 0;
        MonitorEnumProc callback = (IntPtr hDesktop, IntPtr hdc, ref ScreenRect prect, int d) => ++monCount > 0;

        if (EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0))
            Console.WriteLine("You have {0} monitors", monCount);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured while enumerating monitors");

        return monCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but here is what I used:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
internal extern static int fGetSystemMetrics(int metric);

const int SM_CMONITORS = 80;

fGetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
```

Edit: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics